# Are any linear combination of normal random variables, normally distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

It is easy to show that if we have n independent normally distributed random variables, then a linear combination fo them ar normally distributed.

It is also said that if (x1,x2,..,xn) is multivariate normally distributed, but not nececarrily independent, then any linear combination is also normally distributed. This is stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition

But does this mean that any linear combination of normally distributed random variables are normally distributed, even if they are not independent? This will follow from the definition if the joint distribution of set of normally distributed random variables(not nececarrily independent) are jointly multivarite distributed?

Answer (score 13):

> This will follow from the definition if the joint distribution of set of normally distributed random variables(not nececarrily independent) are jointly multivarite distributed?

Yes.

> But does this mean that any linear combination of normally distributed random variables are normally distributed, even if they are not independent?

No. A frequently mentioned counterexample is based on $X$ standard normal and $Y=SX$ with $S=\pm1$ symmetric and independent of $X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are normal but $X+Y$ is not since $P(X+Y=0)=\frac12$, a property that no normal random variable satisfies.

Comment: But if Y = S*X then it is not a linear combination, because S is not a scalar, but a random variable?EDIT: Sorry I see your point now.

Comment: Would you say then that we can partion it in 3 cases?, let X={x1,x2,..xn} be normally random varaibles, either 1. all variables in X are independent, or 2. they are jointly normally distributed, or 3. they are not independent and not jointly normally distributed. In cases 1 and 2 any linear combination of the x's are normally distributed? And in case number 3 we do not know, it may be that they are normally distributed, but it may also be that they are not?

Comment: Yes, except that case 1. is a subcase of case 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the last line. For a Gaussian, since it is continuous, the probability of any particular outcome is 0, so $P(A=0)=0$ for $A\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. But this is true for any continuous variable, not just Gaussian, so should also be true for $X+Y$.

$$P(X+Y=0) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} dx [ p(x) + 0.5 * 1 * p(x) + 0.5 * (-1) * p(x) ] = 0.$$  ?

Answer (score 4):

You need independence. Otherwise the simplest counterexample is $X$ and $-X$, which are both normally distributed, but their sum $X+(-X) = 0$ is not.

Comment: But Wikipedia says that jointly multivariate distributed is sufficient and not independence. So does that mean that in your example, X and -X can not not have a jointly bivariate distribution?

Comment: Think of it this way: a multivariate normal distribution needs a covariance matrix that is strictly positive definite - that's a necessary condition and kills the 'any linear combination, regardless of independence' part. In particular, if one variable is a linear combination of several of the others, that makes the covariance matrix singular.

Comment: The zero random variable **IS** normally distributed.

Comment: only if you consider Dirac's $\delta(x)$ as being a normal distribution, not just a functional limit of normal distributions (which one normally doesn't, as it's not a regular function)

Comment: One "normally" very much considers Dirac measures as members of the normal family. Not doing so quickly leads to a mess, especially in higher dimension. (Unrelated: please use @.)

Answer (score -1):

Just thinking in the univariate case, note that if two RVs are iid, distributed as $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then their sum is distributed as $N(2\mu, 2\sigma^2)$.  If they are correlated with $\rho=1$, it is the same as $2X=X+X$, which is distributed as $N(2\mu, 4\sigma^2)$ - in other words, it is 'stretched out' twice as far in variance.  This makes sense, because uncorrelated would have a standard deviation that grows by $\sqrt 2$, whereas adding to itself must double the standard deviation (which is equivalent to $4\sigma^2$).

All other cases of correlation fall in-between.  Though, as people have pointed out, $pho=-1$ gives you zero as a degenerate point.